# Dominated Convergence of a shifted function

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to pass the limit into the following integral where $f$ is a $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ function.
$$
lim_{y \to x} \int_\mathbb{R} |f(k)|^2|e^{ikx}-e^{iky}|^2 dk
$$
I know that this can be done by dominated convergence but I seem to be unable to find the dominating function.

The goal would be to show that this integral is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something but can't u just use
$$|e^{ikx}-e^{iky}|\leq |e^{ikx}|+ |e^{iky}| \leq 1 +1$$
and then appeal to the $L^2$-property of $f$?

Comment: I don't think you're missing much

Comment: Would not the second inequality actually be an equality in your case?
Also, even doing so would not really have the desired effect as then you could only show that is at most twice the norm of f.

Comment: I think you can use this result to easily find your dominating function.